# control the server side media volume in android

Tags: android-mediaplayer

```
switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testrise", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testlow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
```

This is a code i tried do far...I successfully  implement this ..it control only sounds in device..in my sceneraio i have to control the media that come from server..so not able to control the volume by using this code

Comment: i think there is separate volume control for media file like songs, fm...any suggesttion to acheive this?

Comment: any suggestion please ,,,I struck with that